# SQLAlchemy: Filter existing query by polymorphic subclass (equivalent of `.of_type()` but for `session.query()`)

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

## Question

If I have an existing query for an entity, how can I restrict to it to return only results of a polymorphic subclass of this entity?

## Details

Using the *Employee* / *Engineer* / *Manager* setup from the [Mapping Class Inheritance Hierarchies](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance.html) section of the sqlalchemy documentation:

Imagine I have a complex query that I got from somewhere and which original definition I don't want to change:

```
def get_complex_employee_query():
    """ Super complex query """
    query = session.query(Employee).filter(Employee.name.like('John %'))

    [... imagine a bunch of other `.filter()`, `.join()` and/or `.options()` here ...]

    return query

query = get_complex_query()
```

I know I can filter the query to list only engineers by doing

```
query = query.filter(Employee.type='engineer')
```

But suppose that:

- there are polymorphic subclasses of `Engineer`,
- or that I don't know/care that the `Employee` is `polymorphic_on` the column `type`,
- or that I don't know/care about the correct value for the column `type` to filter only to engineers

Is there a way to apply a `.filter()`, `.options()` or some other method of `query` that will restrict the query to engineers (and subclasses) without knowledge of the specific fields that configure the polymorphic inheritance?

I'm ok with a `.join()` as well, as long as I don't have to know/care about the primary/foreign key relationships between the classes/tables that are part of the polymorphic hierarchy.

## In short

I'd like something like [`Model.relationship.of_type()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance_loading.html#inheritance-of-type) method, but for queries instead of relationships.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect

    [...]
    eng_mapper = inspect(Engineer)
    query.filter(
        eng_mapper.polymorphic_on.in_(
            m.polymorphic_identity
            for m in eng_mapper.polymorphic_iterator()
        ),
    )
```

I'd prefer a slightly less verbose incantation, but this works and doesn't require knowledge of the specific configuration of the polymorphic hierarchy.

## Details

When [`inspect()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/inspection.html) is called on an ORM mapped class, it returns the [`Mapper`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper) for that class. This is identical to the `Model.__mapper__` class attribute.

The `Mapper` contains all information needed to introspect the polymorphic hierarchy. In particular:

- [`.polymorphic_on`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.polymorphic_on) is the field (column) in the model at the top of the hierarchy that contains the polymorphic identity value for a record (e.g. for `Engineer` that would be the `Employee.type` field).
- [`.polymorphic_identity`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.polymorphic_identity) is the value that each instance of the mapped model will have in the `.polymorphic_on` field (e.g. for `Engineer` that would be `"engineer"`).
- [`.polymorphic_iterator()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.polymorphic_iterator) iterates over a collection of model `Mapper`s that includes `Model.__mapper__` and the `.__mapper__` of all subclasses of `Model` recursively (e.g. for `Engineer` that would be an iterator containing only the `Engineer.__mapper__`).

To make it more readable, one could easily turn the above filter expression into a function:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect

def filter_instances_of(cls):
    mapper = inspect(cls)
    return mapper.polymorphic_on.in_(
        m.polymorphic_identity for m in mapper.polymorphic_iterator()
    )
```

And use it like:

```
query = query.filter(
    filter_instances_of(Engineer),
    [... other filter criteria ...]
)
```